# Cannot get wp_redirect to work

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to send an email using wp_mail and then, if mail is sent successfully, redirect user to another page (or, if not successful, to an error page).

My code is shown below. The email is actually sent, so wp_mail is working, but I cannot get the redirect to work.

```
<?php

/*  Template Name: Redirect Template */

?>

<?php

$to = "info@some-domain.com";

$subject = 'This is a test.';
$message = 'This is a test of the wp_mail function.';
$headers = '';

$sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($sent_message) {

    $url_1 = "http://www.some-url.com";
    wp_redirect($url_1);
    exit();

} else {
    $url_2 = "http://www.some-other_url.com";
    wp_redirect($url_2);
    exit();
}

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean the redirect "isn't working"? What happens?

Comment: I'm not redirected to the page specified. In my code above I'm not sent to the new URL, eg to 'http://www.some-url.com'

Comment: A page template is the wrong place to do this sort of processing. It has already been pointed out that the immediate problem is that you have whitespace in your file, but the root problem is that you are using your UI to do backend processing. Why do you need a template at all if all it does is send an email then redirect?

Comment: If a page template is the wrong place to carry out such processing, then where should it be done? I'm none the wiser for your answer.

Comment: @Mekong Your theme's `functions.php` file would be one place. A template file is meant for formatting output to be sent to the browser. Any additional processing (such as determining if you need to redirect) should be handled before the template is even loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the white space between your closing and opening PHP tags. Because you have this space, WordPress is initiating output before the redirect runs (which isn't allowed). Get rid of the following at the top of your file:

```
?>

<?php
```

so that the top of the file becomes:

```
<?php

/*  Template Name: Redirect Template */

$to = "info@some-domain.com";
```

Comment: Thanks Mevius. I removed the white space and it worked straight away. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. On a related note, you don't need to close all of those `<?php ?>` tags in your code. To simplify things, you could just have one opening tag at the top of the file, and none after that.